# Compare two pointers

Tags: pointers, fortran, fortran90

I recently came across the question of how to compare two pointers in Fortran. In C one can compare two pointers with `(pA == pB)` (with `pA` and `pB` being pointers) as they are just addresses. But in fortran pointers are more than pure memory addresses. The code `if(pa.ne.pb)` (with `pa` and `pb` being pointers of the same type) gives me an error

> Operands of comparison operator '.ne.' at (1) are
>   TYPE(sometype)/TYPE(sometype)

where sometype is the type the pointer is pointing to.

Is there a way to compare whether two pointers point to the same target? Or do I have to create a `.ne.`-operator for the type being pointed to?

Comment: [This isn't an answer, but] for the example `if(pa.ne.pb)` this isn't a comparison of the pointers, but of the targets of the pointers.  Creating a naive defined operator for this type won't help solve the problem of seeing whether the targets are the same variable (rather than having the same value).

Comment: You're probably looking for the intrinsic function `associated`, see your favourite reference material for an explanation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [High Performance Mark comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302738/compare-two-pointers#comment54406268_33302738) the `associated` intrinsic can partly do what you want:

```
if (.not.ASSOCIATED(pa, pb)) ...
```

In many cases, using `associated` with two pointer arguments will tell you whether the two targets "occupy the same storage units".  In some senses this is the case when the pointers are pointing to the same target.

```
integer, target :: a
integer, pointer :: pa, pb
pa=>a; pb=>a

print*, ASSOCIATED(pa, pb)
```

Alas, things aren't so simple.

Another restriction for scalar targets is that they are not zero-sized storage.  Take the following case

```
type t
end type t

type(t), target :: a
type(t), pointer :: pa, pb
pa=>a; pb=>a

print*, ASSOCIATED(pa, pb)
```

The output of this, if a variable of type `t` has zero-sized storage, must be `.FALSE.`, even though they are certainly the same target.  The storage size of an object of type `t` is an implementation detail.

The same holds for zero-sized arrays, although it is clear that the result here is `.FALSE.`:

```
integer, target :: a(0)
integer, pointer :: pa(:), pb(:)
pa=>a; pb=>a

print*, ASSOCIATED(pa, pb)
```

If you have such pathological cases of the first kind that you care about there may be a possibility to consider using C addresses and Fortran 2003 C interoperability.

The `c_associated` function compares the C addresses determined by `c_loc`.  Continuing the above code with `type(t)` targets,

```
print*, C_ASSOCIATED(C_LOC(pa), C_LOC(pb))
```

may be more forgiving.  Again, whether it works depends on the implementation.

This approach with C addresses will not help in the case of zero-length strings or zero-sized arrays: using `c_loc` is prohibited in these cases.

To conclude, it is generally the case that `ASSOCIATED(pa, pb)` returns `.TRUE.` if and only if `pa` and `pb` point to the same target, but there are exceptions in both directions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm a little ashamed that I didn't know about `associated` being capable of doing this. But I anyway wouldn't have known about the details you provided.

Answer (score 4):

The [associated()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ASSOCIATED.html) function takes a second optional pointer argument. You can then test if both pointers are associated with the same target:

```
if (associated(pA, pB)
```